# Prove maximum and minimum of function

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the function:

$ f(x): R \to R, x \to {3x \over x^2 -2x+4}$

Use your favourite plotting tool to take a look at the graph and observe where the function obtains its maximum and its minimum. Formally show that they really are the maximum and the minimum of the function.

Using plotting tool we can see that $f(x)=  {3x \over x^2 -2x+4}$ has maximum at  ${3 \over 2}$  and minimum at $ - {1 \over2}$.

$f({3 \over 2}) = {18 \over 13}$

$f(-{1 \over 2}) = -{6 \over 13}$

I have no idea what to do next. I have to use this definition:
For any function $f: S → R$ we say that f has a minimum at $c ∈ S$ if $f(c) ≤ f(x)$ for all $x ∈ S$ and a maximum at $c$ if $f(c) ≥ f(x$) for all $x ∈ S$.

Comment: What about calculating the derivative of $f$ and look where it gets zero?

Comment: @GyroGearloose That is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. yes, but it is the first step the OP is missing. Using "plotting tool" indicates the OP is not even aware of derivatives at all. No down-vote, on the question, as it appears to be asked in all honesty to learn better.

Comment: Please, choose the tags carefully. This question is not about functional analysis. Read its descriptions of the tags choosing them.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Not the downvoter, but the OP has not shown any effort. But yes to OP: first use the first-derivative check to verify if the candidate points are critical, and the second derivative to verify if they are local minima/maxima. Edit your question with the attempts made.

Comment: Actually the maximum is at $x=2$ with $f(2)=\frac{3}{2}$. Compute $f(x)-\frac{3}{2}$ and factor the result.

Comment: I don't agree with the claim that the OP has not shown any effort. They plot the function, try (unsuccessfully) to interpret it, and correctly recalled the definition they had to use.

Answer (score 1):

The result from your "plotting tool" is wrong. [The extrema seem to be rather](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%5Cfrac%7B3x%7D%7Bx%5E2-2x%2B4%7D)
$$f(-2)=-\frac12\ \text{ and }\ f(2)=\frac32.$$
(Strangely enough, these extreme *values* $-\frac12,\frac32$ were precisely the *points* at which you thought the extrema were attained.)

To prove that guess, don't bother about derivatives. The most elementary way is to apply the definitions you recalled, i.e. to prove that
$$\forall x\in\Bbb R,\quad-\frac12\le{3x \over x^2 -2x+4}\le\frac32$$
i.e.
(since the denominator $x^2 -2x+4$ is always positive)
$$-(x^2 -2x+4)\le6x\le3(x^2 -2x+4)$$
or equivalently
$$x^2+4x+4\ge0\ \text{ and }\ x^2 -4x+4\ge0.$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you. I totally didn't understand this topic (((

Comment: I understood your answer, thank you for help

Comment: I am glad, then. [Don't thank](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The possible places for minimum and maximum are:

1. Points where the function is not differentiable.
2. Points where the derivative is zero.
3. If defined on a closed interval, at the borders of the interval.

So find those points. Lucky for you, the denominator is always >= 3.

Comment: How could I do it?